# How come computer science books are so relaxed about specifying which set variables/values belong too?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

> How come computer science books are so relaxed about specifying which set variables/values belong too ?

I've read several books on algorithms like CLRS's Introduction to Algorithms, Sedgewick's An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms etc.

> How come these kind of books are so sloppy about telling which set values/variables belong too ?

To give some examples:

Introducing Big-O notation books don't mention the domain and co-domain of the functions $f(N)$ and $g(N)$. Neither, is it mentioned which set the constant $C$ belongs too.

Introducing Generation Functions nothing is said about the values of the sequence $a_0, a_1, \ldots$. In mathematics these are complex numbers, but nothing is said here.

Comment: Especially regarding Big-O notation, impreciseness starts even earlier. I do not understand the benefit of saying, e.g., $g(n) = \mathcal{O}(f(n))$ instead of $g(n) \in \mathcal{O}(f(n))$.

Comment: While this is a good question in the sense that it should *certainly* be asked, it is not a good fit for this site. It does not admit objectively correct answers; the authors have their own reasons. Also, while this is true for some it is almost certainly not true for *all* CS books.

Comment: That said, I can offer some guesses: 1) The books you name are *textbooks*, designed to accompany a university course. The authors may assume certain prior knowledge; for instance, CLRS *explicitly* mention that they assume some programming and mathematical prior knowledge. 2) The details either don't matter or are clear from context. (I dislike this explanation/excuse myself, but I have heard it many times.)

Comment: The same applies to the Wikipedia article on Big-O. So it is assumed we always are in the real numbers otherwise anything else is being said ?

Comment: In algorithm analysis, we even have $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. (I find the formal rigor in many Wikipedia articles lacking, and many of the descriptions misleading. For all but basic definitions, I can not recommend Wikipedia where TCS is concerned.)

Comment: You **could** define $f,g$ as arbitrary partial functions over the same domain and codomain, with both domain and codomain being an ordered structure; then you would choose the constants from the codomain and whenever $f$ is defined, $g$ also needs to be defined. The use of such an abstract definition to CS people would be almost zero and it would confuse students unnecessarily (who I've been told don't do too well with the formal definitions of Landau notation anyway). The constant $c$ is always understood to be from the shared codomain of $f,g$ since $c \cdot g(x)$ needs to be defined.

Comment: Come to think of it, you wouldn't even need the domain to be an ordered structure, an ordered set (without any operations defined on it) would do. As mentioned above, the codomain is assumed to have multiplication defined on it, so that needs to be an ordered structure.

Comment: @Raphael Which textbooks on CS do you know that are rigorous in the same way math textbooks for pure math degrees are? I don't think I've ever come across one.

Comment: @G.Bach I don't know any such math books, and also few English (basic) CS (text)books. So I'm not really equipped to answer that request. (Also, I would be surprised if *all* math books are rigorous. Mathematicians have their own set of implicit assumptions, and often a less than formal proof style.)

Comment: @G.Bach Regarding CS students and formal definitions, well. That may just be due to a tradition of bad teaching and/or considering the mix of engineers, scientists and mathematicians you have before you. I find that if properly trained, students have little trouble with understanding formal definitions. (If you want to continue either of the discussions, please head over to [chat].)